# How to embed a string within a string in python2.7, that has escaped quotes in it?

Tags: python, string, formatting, sms

I am trying with replace two literals with variable for for a payload for an sms:

```
import requests
url = "https://api.aql.com/v2/sms/send"
token='07ae4cca3f90a49347ccb5cfghypdngthwss85d9ce71862663e4b8162b366ba6c2db8f5f'
msg = "Ambient temperature has dropped to 10 Deg.C"
phone = "441234567890"

payload = "{\"destinations\" : [\"447753448024\"], \"message\": \"Hello, I am a message\"}"
headers = {
    'x-auth-token': token,
    'content-type': "application/json"
}

response = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

I wish to insert the variables phone and msg in place or the literals

Any help will be gratefully received

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Modifying JSON with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32473057/modifying-json-with-python)

Answer (score 0):

You may use `json` attribute from `.post()` it'll handle the `content-type` header and the conversion from `dict` to `str`

```
url = "https://api.aql.com/v2/sms/send"
token='07ae4cca3f90a49347ccb5cfghypdngthwss85d9ce71862663e4b8162b366ba6c2db8f5f'
msg = "Ambient temperature has dropped to 10 Deg.C"
phone = "441234567890"

payload = {'destinations':[phone], 'message':msg}
response = requests.post(url, json=payload, headers={'x-auth-token': token})
```

Comment: Sorry but i I get the error: destination parameters are required, thanks anyway

Comment: @AWR Look the edit, you can remove the content-type and the json.dumps, using `json` parameter from `post`

Comment: Yes. Thanks once again :-)